# Find a differentiable function $f : E \subset_\text{open} \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^m$ such that $f'$ is not continuous everywhere on $E$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Find a differentiable function $f : E \subset_\text{open} \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^m$ such that $f': E \subset_\text{open} \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ is not continuous everywhere on $E$.

It is clear to me that if $f$ is differentiable at some $x \in E$ then there exists a linear transformation $A$ from $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^m$ such that

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah\|} {\|h\|} = 0.$$

We usually write $f'(x)=A$ and $A$ is said to be the total derivative of $f$ at $x$.  Since $f$ is differentiable on $E$ so for each $x \in E$, $f'(x)$ exists as a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^m$. Thus $f'$ is a function from $E$ into $L(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^m)$. Now my question is :

"Does $\exists$ any differentiable function $f : E \subset_\text{open} \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^m$ such that $f' : E \subset_\text{open} \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow L(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^m)$ is not continuous everywhere on $E$?"

Please give me such an example if there is any.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Expressions like "not continuous everywhere" should be avoided because they are ambiguous. Does it mean "discontinuous everywhere" or does it mean "not everywhere-continuous"?

Answer (score 0):

Take any example in dimension 1,  $F(x)= x^2\sin ({1\over x})$, for instance. Then take $f(x_1,..,x_n)=F(x_1)$.